# AutoMapper differences between versions?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper 6.2.2 .

I have 2 classes :

```
public class BBB
{
    public int b { get; set; }
}


public class AAA
{
    public int a { get; set; }
}
```

Please notice that they have different property names.

When I write a simple console application that uses mapping between `AAA` `->` `BBB` , I do NOT get an exception :

```
var a = new AAA();
var b = new BBB();

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<AAA, BBB>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var dto = mapper.Map<BBB>(a);
Console.WriteLine(dto); //{b=0}
```

*(No Exceptions).*

However, If I use .Net Core with :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

And then in controller :

```
[HttpGet]
public object Get()
    {
        var a = new AAA();
        var t = _mapper.Map<AAA, BBB>(a);
        return t;
    }
```

Then , I DO see exception :

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException:  Unmapped members were
> found. Review the types and members below. Add a custom mapping
> expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the
> source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
> ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
> =========== AAA -> BBB (Destination member list) AAA -> BBB (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: b

**Question:**

Why do I see exceptions in the second case? (*while not appearing in the first case*)

Comment: seems like mapping not actually occur in your console app and it returns default value

Comment: then take a read about  `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); ` https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html "Executing this code produces an AutoMapperConfigurationException, with a descriptive message."

Comment: @demo Thanks for reply. If I remove `AssertConfigurationIsValid` it still yields an exception

Comment: @RoyiNamir in the screenshot you provided where it's working, both classes have a property `int a` while in the question code one class has `int a` and another has `int b`, so of course it doesn't map it.

Comment: @LLL it was a proof for the first comment where he said that the mapper doesn't actually occur. so i wanted to show him that it does work

Comment: @RoyiNamir Still you provided example where it is working, but different one. If you try with example you posted, it should not work in even in console app.

Comment: And I'd add `AssertCofnigurationIsValid` in console app as well, to fully reporduce circumstances.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn you are right. when I added  it in console  , it also fails :https://i.imgur.com/xA46vcF.jpg. But now  - it makes me wonder - why does it fail in the .net core version even if i remove(!) the assertion ? https://i.imgur.com/pKZiUDs.jpg

Comment: Maybe AutoMapper, when implelentning transition to Net Core has fixed some bugs as well (to me it is a bug, when there's invalid configuration, as you provided, and it is silent about it). I used AutoMapper on NET Core and it throws in case of such configuration.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn plz supply an answer so i can select it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference you see is due to differences in your own implementation.

At first it was a guess, later confirmed by OP, so here it is:

Console version did not use `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` which caused invalid configuration to fail, without it, AutoMapper silently hid the failure.

Also, it was asked that even without the `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` method, in NET Core version AutoMapper fails. My guess is that AutoMapper authors decided not to hide configuration failures and implemented it in new version, so it fails when invalid mapping is applied.